# Expss call returns blank table

Tags: r, expss

Attempting to call Expss from within a function. However it returns an empty table.

```
s1_a<-c("a","b","b")
s1_b<-c("a","a","b")
df<-data.frame(s1_a,s1_b)


multi<-function(v) {
df %>%
tab_cells(mrset_p("v")) %>%
tab_stat_cpct() %>%
tab_sort_desc() %>%
tab_pivot()
}

multi("s1_")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't need quotes in the `mrset_p`:

```
library(expss)
s1_a<-c("a","b","b")
s1_b<-c("a","a","b")
df<-data.frame(s1_a,s1_b)


multi<-function(v) {
    df %>%
        tab_cells(mrset_p(v)) %>% # no quotes
        tab_stat_cpct() %>%
        tab_sort_desc() %>%
        tab_pivot()
}

multi("s1_")
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there cases where quotation marks would be required?

Comment: @CK7 When you use quotes `mrset_p("v")` just search for variables which contains "v" and don't use variable `v` . So if you need to get variables with some constant pattern you can type this pattern in quotes.